forward-looking versus backward-looking timestamp conventions
I am collecting sensordata in a database. Observations are stored at an hourly or daily resolution, as timestamp - value. I have to deceide to make the timestamps

forward-looking (i.e 01/01/24 02:00 refers to the period 01/01/24 02:00-03:00
backward-looking i.e 01/01/24 02:00 refers to the period 01/01/24 01:00 02:00

I am not aware of a standard for this, although metereological data mostly uses backward-looking timestamps. forward-looking timestamps seem, however more consistent when also storing daily values.
The choice seems arbitrary, but there may be important considerations that I am missing. Any input on this would be appreciated.

Key points for timestamp choice:

Consistency
Industry standards
Data clarity
System compatibility
Aggregation ease
Timezone handling
Edge case management

Choose one, document it clearly. Both can work if used consistently.

You could add to your list of options a mid-point time stamp like |-sampling-start....t....sampling-end-|. Just make sure to document it clearly. And concerning best practice, use ISO8601 format if you store timestamps as a string (not "01/01/24 02:00").
